# How can I use parentheses in C++ macro parameters?

Tags: c++, macros, escaping, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I need to use parentheses in my actual parameters for a macro, but the parentheses appear to be changing the behavior of the comma separating the macro parameters.

I had my preprocessor dump its output into a text file, so I could see what it was producing.
Then I performed a basic test to confirm the behavior.

```
#define MACRO_TEST_1( X , Y ) X && Y

MACRO_TEST_1 ( A , B )
// Desired result: A && B
// Actual result:  A && B

MACRO_TEST_1 ( ( C , D ) )
// Desired result: ( C && D )
// Actual result:  ( C , D ) &&
// Warning: "not enough actual parameters for macro 'MACRO_TEST_1'"
```

It appears that adding an opening parenthese to the first parameter, and a closing parenthese to the second parameter, causes the preprocessor to treat the comma as ***part*** of the first parameter, and therefore assumes that I ***did not supply*** a second parameter at all.
This is evidenced by the warning, as well as the preprocessor output showing nothing after the `&&`.

So my question is, how can I tell the preprocessor that the comma seperates the parameters, even though the parameters have parentheses in them?

I tried escaping the parentheses or the comma, but this made no difference.
(Same results, just with the escape character inserted into the preprocessor output.)

Comment: Do you really need to do this with macros? Why?

Comment: @FrankPuffer I won't go into details. It's an odd situation, working with old code - probably temporary. I figure there's probably a lesser-known trick I'd have to use to get parentheses in there, and that's what I need for the time-being.

Comment: @FrankPuffer Wouldn't functions have the same problem? `func(1, 2)` is 2 arguments, `func((1, 2))` is just one argument.

Comment: I don't understand why you're putting the extra parentheses in the call. The whole point of parentheses is to group things together. When you wrap a function or macro argument with parentheses, it becomes a single argument.

Comment: @Barmar I understand. My thought is, since this is the preprocessor we're talking about, aren't there usually workarounds for rules like this? I haven't known the preprocessor to impose limits that make certain results impossible in the past ... it just seems odd to me that this would be impossible.

Comment: The preprocessor is very simple, it doesn't provide any mechanism to manipulate the arguments at the character level. it just provides simple substitutions. There's no way to remove the extra pareentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I technically found a solution, albeit ugly.
You have to define symbols for the parentheses characters.

```
#define OP (
#define CP )

#define MACRO_TEST_1( X , Y ) X && Y

MACRO_TEST_1 ( A , B )
// Desired result: A && B
// Actual result:  A && B

MACRO_TEST_1 ( OP C , D CP )
// Desired result: ( C && D )
// Actual result:  ( C && D )
```

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is, how can I tell the preprocessor that the comma
>   separates the parameters, even though the parameters have parentheses
>   in them?

I think that there is no way, at least in such macro implementation.

From the [gcc.gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html#Macro-Arguments):

> To invoke a macro that takes arguments, you write the name of the
>   macro followed by a list of actual arguments in parentheses, separated
>   by commas.
>
> Leading and trailing whitespace in each argument is dropped, and all
>   whitespace between the tokens of an argument is reduced to a single
>   space. *Parentheses within each argument must balance; a comma within
>   such parentheses does not end the argument.*
>
> You cannot leave out arguments entirely; if a macro takes two
>   arguments, there must be exactly one comma at the top level of its
>   argument list.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like a situation where an escape character SHOULD reasonably be able to change the meaning of the parantheses characters. It's a shame that isn't the case - macros could be more broad/flexible if escaping the parentheses was a possibility.

Comment: @Giffyguy In any case macros are just a C legacy which can't be flexible enough for many purposes, so... we have what we have :)